# Cake PHP Association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**I have a 3 tables**

1. Table `articles` - Contains a list of all Articles.
2. Table `articles_tags` - Contains a list of all Article Tags
3. Table `articles_tag_names` - Contains a list of Tag Names

Structure for `articles` table is `id`|`aticle_body`|`article_author_id`|`article_date`.

Structure for `articles_tags` table is `id`|`article_id`|`article_tag_id`.

Structure for `articles_tag_names` table is `id`|`article_tag_name`.

I want to fetch all or specific articles together with their respective tag names using Table associations. I fruitlessly tried the following.

**In App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable.php.**

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->hasMany('ArticlesTags', [
            'dependent' => true,
            'cascadeCallbacks' => false,
            'propertyName' => 'article_tags'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**In App\Model\Table\ArticlesTagsTable.php.**

```
class ArticlesTagsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->belongsToMany('Articles')
        ->setForeignKey('article_id');
        /** I need ideas on how to associate with ArticlesTagNamesTable **/
    }
}
```

**In App\Model\Table\ArticlesTagNamesTable.php.**

```
class ArticlesTagNamesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        /** I need ideas on how to associate with  ArticlesTagsTable **/
    }
}
```

**I am expecting an output like this below.**

```
  [
      [
        'id' => 145,
        'article_body' => This is my first article body,
        'article_author_id' => 13,
        'article_date' => March 18 2017 19:00:12,
        'article_tags' => [
                            [
                              'id' => 3,
                              'article_id' => 145,
                              'article_tag_id' => 32,
                              'article_tag_name' => cakephp
                            ],
                            [
                              'id' => 4,
                              'article_id' => 145,
                              'article_tag_id' => 33,
                              'article_tag_name' => java
                            ]
                          ]
      ],
      [
        'id' => 146,
        'article_body' => This is my second article body,
        'article_author_id' => 13,
        'article_date' => March 18 2017 22:00:16,
        'article_tags' =>  [
                            [
                              'id' => 5,
                              'article_id' => 146,
                              'article_tag_id' => 34,
                              'article_tag_name' => php
                            ]
                          ]
      ]
    ]
```

**OR**

```
  [
      [
        'id' => 145,
        'article_body' => This is my first article body,
        'article_author_id' => 13,
        'article_date' => March 18 2017 19:00:12,
        'article_tags' => [
                            [
                              'id' => 3,
                              'article_id' => 145,
                              'article_tag_id' => 32,
                              'articles_tag_names' => [
                                'id' => 12
                                'article_tag_name' => cakephp
                               ]
                            ],
                            [
                              'id' => 4,
                              'article_id' => 145,
                              'article_tag_id' => 33,                                  
                              'articles_tag_names' => [
                                'id' => 13
                                'article_tag_name' => java
                               ]
                            ]
                          ]
      ],
      [
        'id' => 146,
        'article_body' => This is my second article body,
        'article_author_id' => 13,
        'article_date' => March 18 2017 22:00:16,
        'article_tags' =>  [
                            [
                              'id' => 5,
                              'article_id' => 146,
                              'article_tag_id' => 34,
                              'articles_tag_names' => [
                                'id' => 14
                                'article_tag_name' => php
                               ]
                            ]
                          ]
      ]
    ]
```

.... etc etc

Can someone help with combining Articles, ArticleTags and ArticleTagNames using CakePHP associations or joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first advice is to [follow CakePHP conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) to do this easily.

You will end up with something like this.

Articles table

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Authors table

```
CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Tags table

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

ArticlesTags table

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx1` (`article_id`),
  KEY `idx2` (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Articles table class

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('articles');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsTo('Authors', [
            'foreignKey' => 'author_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_tags'
        ]);
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['author_id'], 'Authors'));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Tags table class

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class TagsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tags');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'article_id',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_tags'
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

Articles controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $articles = $this->Articles->find()
            ->contain(['Authors', 'Tags'])
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->toArray();
        debug($articles);
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

You will end up with:

```
/src/Controller/ArticlesController.php (line 28)
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'body' => 'Lorem ipsum',
        'author_id' => (int) 1,
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2018-03-19T00:00:25+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'tags' => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'id' => (int) 1,
                'name' => 'First tag',
                '_joinData' => [
                    'id' => (int) 1,
                    'article_id' => (int) 1,
                    'tag_id' => (int) 1
                ]
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                'id' => (int) 2,
                'name' => 'Second Tag',
                '_joinData' => [
                    'id' => (int) 2,
                    'article_id' => (int) 1,
                    'tag_id' => (int) 2
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'author' => [
            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'Xander'
        ]
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'body' => 'Follow CakePHP conventions!',
        'author_id' => (int) 1,
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2018-03-19T00:00:57+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'tags' => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'id' => (int) 1,
                'name' => 'First tag',
                '_joinData' => [
                    'id' => (int) 3,
                    'article_id' => (int) 2,
                    'tag_id' => (int) 1
                ]
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                'id' => (int) 3,
                'name' => 'Third Tag',
                '_joinData' => [
                    'id' => (int) 4,
                    'article_id' => (int) 2,
                    'tag_id' => (int) 3
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'author' => [
            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'Xander'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Guillaume this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.